# gulp-eslint not showing any error on console

Tags: node.js, gulp

I have defined a gulp task like this

```
var lint = require('gulp-eslint');
gulp.task('lint', function() {
    return gulp.src(config.paths.js)
        .pipe(lint({config: 'eslint.config.json'}))
        .pipe(lint.format());
});
```

and a js file like this

```
$ = jQuery = require('jquery');

var App = console.log('hello from browserfiy');

module.exports = App;
```

when I edit my js file by adding `var test = 15; var test = 20;` and save, lint does not show any error message on console, although from console I can see lint was kicked in like

```
Starting 'lint'...
Finished 'lint'  29ms
```

eslint.config.json

```
{
  "ecmaFeatures": {
    "jsx": true
  },
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "node": true,
    "jquery": true
  },
  "rules": {
    "quotes": 0,
    "no-trailing-spaces": 0,
    "eol-last": 0,
    "no-unused-vars": 0,
    "no-underscore-dangle": 0,
    "no-alert": 0,
    "no-lone-blocks": 0
  },
  "globals": {
    jQuery: true,
    $: true
  }
}
```

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with your setup... Have you by any chance accidentally disabled the `no-redeclare` rule ?

Comment: Maybe post that as an answer and mark it as solved :)
Cheers

Comment: You also did the pluralsight course? ;-) I had the same issue. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: I'm also doing the exact course, had the same issue, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As seen in the comments, you can add this to your eslint configuration to get an error when redeclaring a variable :

```
 "no-redeclare": 1
```

[Rule documentation](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-redeclare.html)